New project with no code changes, cargo build-sbf resulting in many (44) errors
I created a new project, with cargo init project --lib.
I added these dependencies:
solana-program = "1.18.11"
solana-client = "1.18.11"
solana-sdk = "1.18.11",
ran cargo add solana-program,
and ran cargo build-sbf (also tried cargo build-bpf), and it's resulting in 44 errors, such as:
error[E0425]: cannot find value 'IPPROTO_IP' in module 'sys' --> src/socket.rs:1582:22
How can I fix this?
Here's some of the error output:
error[E0583]: file not found for module `sys`
   --> src/lib.rs:179:1
    |
179 | mod sys;
    | ^^^^^^^^
    |
    = help: to create the module `sys`, create file "/home/abcdefg/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/socket2-0.5.6/src/sys.rs" or "/home/abcdefg/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/socket2-0.5.6/src/sys/mod.rs"
    = note: if there is a `mod sys` elsewhere in the crate already, import it with `use crate::...` instead

error[E0432]: unresolved import `crate::sys::IoSourceState`
  --> src/io_source.rs:12:5
   |
12 | use crate::sys::IoSourceState;
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ no `IoSourceState` in `sys`

error[E0425]: cannot find function `is` in this scope
  --> src/lib.rs:98:6
   |
98 |     !is(stream)
   |      ^^ not found in this scope

error[E0432]: unresolved import `crate::sys::tcp`
  --> src/net/tcp/listener.rs:15:17
   |
15 | use crate::sys::tcp::{bind, listen, new_for_addr};
   |                 ^^^ could not find `tcp` in `sys`

error: Socket2 doesn't support the compile target
   --> src/lib.rs:182:1
    |
182 | compile_error!("Socket2 doesn't support the compile target");
    | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

error[E0432]: unresolved import `crate::sys::tcp`
  --> src/net/tcp/stream.rs:13:17
   |
13 | use crate::sys::tcp::{connect, new_for_addr};
   |                 ^^^ could not find `tcp` in `sys`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0425`.
error: could not compile `atty` (lib) due to previous error
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
error[E0433]: failed to resolve: could not find `Selector` in `sys`
   --> src/poll.rs:312:18
    |
312 |             sys::Selector::new().map(|selector| Poll {
    |                  ^^^^^^^^ could not find `Selector` in `sys`

error[E0433]: failed to resolve: could not find `event` in `sys`
  --> src/event/event.rs:24:14
   |
24 |         sys::event::token(&self.inner)
   |              ^^^^^ could not find `event` in `sys`

error[E0432]: unresolved imports `crate::sys::c_int`, `crate::sys::sa_family_t`, `crate::sys::sockaddr`, `crate::sys::sockaddr_in`, `crate::sys::sockaddr_in6`, `crate::sys::sockaddr_storage`, `crate::sys::socklen_t`, `crate::sys::AF_INET`, `crate::sys::AF_INET6`, `crate::sys::AF_UNIX`
  --> src/sockaddr.rs:11:5
   |
11 |     c_int, sa_family_t, sockaddr, sockaddr_in, sockaddr_in6, sockaddr_storage, socklen_t, AF_INET,
   |     ^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^ no `AF_INET` in `sys`
   |     |      |            |         |            |             |                 |
   |     |      |            |         |            |             |                 no `socklen_t` in `sys`
   |     |      |            |         |            |             no `sockaddr_storage` in `sys`
   |     |      |            |         |            no `sockaddr_in6` in `sys`
   |     |      |            |         no `sockaddr_in` in `sys`
   |     |      |            no `sockaddr` in `sys`
   |     |      no `sa_family_t` in `sys`
   |     no `c_int` in `sys`
12 |     AF_INET6, AF_UNIX,
   |     ^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^ no `AF_UNIX` in `sys`
   |     |
   |     no `AF_INET6` in `sys`
   |
   = help: consider importing one of these items instead:
           std::ffi::c_int
           std::os::raw::c_int
           core::ffi::c_int
   = help: consider importing this module instead:
           crate::sockaddr

error[E0433]: failed to resolve: could not find `event` in `sys`
  --> src/event/event.rs:38:14
   |
38 |         sys::event::is_readable(&self.inner)
   |              ^^^^^ could not find `event` in `sys`

error[E0432]: unresolved imports `crate::sys::c_int`, `crate::sys::getsockopt`, `crate::sys::setsockopt`, `crate::sys::Bool`
  --> src/socket.rs:23:24
   |
23 | use crate::sys::{self, c_int, getsockopt, setsockopt, Bool};
   |                        ^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^ no `Bool` in `sys`
   |                        |      |           |
   |                        |      |           no `setsockopt` in `sys`
   |                        |      no `getsockopt` in `sys`
   |                        no `c_int` in `sys`
   |
   = help: consider importing one of these items instead:
           std::ffi::c_int
           std::os::raw::c_int
           core::ffi::c_int

error[E0433]: failed to resolve: could not find `event` in `sys`
  --> src/event/event.rs:43:14
   |
43 |         sys::event::is_writable(&self.inner)
   |              ^^^^^ could not find `event` in `sys`

error[E0432]: unresolved import `sys::c_int`
   --> src/lib.rs:184:5
    |
184 | use sys::c_int;
    |     ^^^^^^^^^^ no `c_int` in `sys`
    |
help: consider importing one of these items instead
    |
184 | use core::ffi::c_int;
    |     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
184 | use std::ffi::c_int;
    |     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
184 | use std::os::raw::c_int;
    |     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

error[E0433]: failed to resolve: could not find `event` in `sys`
  --> src/event/event.rs:68:14
   |
68 |         sys::event::is_error(&self.inner)
   |              ^^^^^ could not find `event` in `sys`

error[E0433]: failed to resolve: could not find `event` in `sys`
  --> src/event/event.rs:99:14
   |
99 |         sys::event::is_read_closed(&self.inner)
   |              ^^^^^ could not find `event` in `sys`

error[E0433]: failed to resolve: could not find `event` in `sys`
   --> src/event/event.rs:129:14
    |
129 |         sys::event::is_write_closed(&self.inner)
    |              ^^^^^ could not find `event` in `sys`

error[E0433]: failed to resolve: could not find `event` in `sys`
   --> src/event/event.rs:151:14
    |
151 |         sys::event::is_priority(&self.inner)
    |              ^^^^^ could not find `event` in `sys`
error[E0433]: failed to resolve: could not find `event` in `sys`
   --> src/event/event.rs:173:14
    |
173 |         sys::event::is_aio(&self.inner)
    |              ^^^^^ could not find `event` in `sys`

error[E0433]: failed to resolve: could not find `event` in `sys`
   --> src/event/event.rs:183:14
    |
183 |         sys::event::is_lio(&self.inner)
    |              ^^^^^ could not find `event` in `sys`


Can you post the full error list?

I ran cargo clean and it got rid of most errors. It is erroring that it can't find getrandom. I added the getrandom package to dev dependencies per the documentation: https://solana.com/docs/programs/lang-rust#depending-on-rand

error: target is not supported, for more information see: https://docs.rs/getrandom/#unsupported-targets
--> src/lib.rs:267:9
|
267 | /         compile_error!("
268 | |             target is not supported, for more information see: 
269 | |             https://docs.rs/getrandom/#unsupported-targets
270 | |         ");
| |__________^
Compiling parking_lot v0.12.1
error[E0433]: failed to resolve: use of undeclared crate or module imp
--> src/lib.rs:291:5
|
291 |     imp::getrandom_inner(dest)
|     ^^^ use of undeclared crate or module imp

Solana programs have to be deterministic, so random numbers are not available

I'm aware the random crate is not supported because of what you said. I managed to fix it on one computer, downgrading everything solana related to 1.17.17, and some other fix I can't recall.

Since Rust based on-chain programs must run be deterministic while running in a resource-constrained, single-threaded environment, they have some limitations on various libraries.
Solana Programs are constrained to run deterministically, so random numbers are not available.
Sometimes a program may depend on a crate that depends itself on rand even if the program does not use any of the random number functionality. If a program depends on rand, the compilation will fail because there is no get-random support for Solana.
You can find the full list of restrictions here
